# Fundamental vector field on principal bundle commutes with special horizontal vector field

Tags: fiber-bundles, connections

In the `note 1` of the Wikipedia `Exterior covariant derivative` article, it mentions some assertion that is crucial to the proof, but doesn't give a proof of the assertion itself. The assertion is something equivalent to the following.

Assertion: $(P,π,M)$ is a principal $G$-bundle with a given principal connection. $X$ is a fundamental vector field on $P$, $Y$ is a vector field on $M$, $Z$ is the horizontal lift of $Y$ by the principal connection. Then there is $[X,Z]=0$.

Can this be proved? I'm not sure whether $Z$ has to be a horizontal lift instead of just any horizontal vector field on $P$ for the above to be true.